# Reading BigQuery Numeric Data Type From Table Using SchemaAndRecord class

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

While Developing my code I used the below code snippet to read the table data from BigQuery.

```
PCollection<ReasonCode> gpseEftReasonCodes = input.
                apply("Reading xxyyzz",
                        BigQueryIO.read(new 
                                ReadTable<ReasonCode>(ReasonCode.class))
                        .withoutValidation().withTemplateCompatibility()
                        .fromQuery("Select * from dataset.xxyyzz").usingStandardSql()
                        .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(xxyyzz.class))
```

Read Table Class:

```
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
public class ReadTable<T> implements SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Gson gson = new Gson();
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadTable.class);
    private final Counter countingRecords = Metrics.counter(ReadTable.class,"Reading Records EFT Report");
    private  Class<T> class1;

    public ReadTable(Class<T> class1) {
        this.class1 = class1;
    }

    public T apply(SchemaAndRecord schemaAndRecord) {
        Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        int counter = 0;
        try {

            GenericRecord s = schemaAndRecord.getRecord();
            org.apache.avro.Schema s1 = s.getSchema();
            for (Field f : s1.getFields()) {
                counter++;
                mapping.put(f.name(), null==s.get(f.name())?null:String.valueOf(s.get(counter)));
            }
            countingRecords.inc();
            JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(mapping);
            return gson.fromJson(jsonElement, class1);
        }catch(Exception mp) {
            LOG.error("Found Wrong Mapping for the Record: "+mapping);
            mp.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So After Reading the data from Bigquery I was mapping data from SchemaAndRecord to pojo I was getting value for columns whose Data type is Numeric mention below.

```
 last_update_amount=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]
```

My Expectation was I will get exact value but getting the HyperByte Buffer the version I am using is Apache beam 2.12.0.
If any more information is needed then please let me know.

Way 2 Tried:

````
GenericRecord s = schemaAndRecord.getRecord();

            org.apache.avro.Schema s1 = s.getSchema();
            for (Field f : s1.getFields()) {
                counter++;      
                mapping.put(f.name(), null==s.get(f.name())?null:String.valueOf(s.get(counter)));
                if(f.name().equalsIgnoreCase("reason_code_id")) {
                    BigDecimal numericValue =
                            new Conversions.DecimalConversion()
                                .fromBytes((ByteBuffer)s.get(f.name()) , Schema.create(s1.getType()), s1.getLogicalType());
                    System.out.println("Numeric Con"+numericValue);
                }
                else {
                        System.out.println("Else Condition "+f.name());
                }
            }
            ```

Facing Issue:

2019-05-24 (14:10:37) org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Can't create a: RECORD


Way 2:

    GenericRecord s = schemaAndRecord.getRecord();

                org.apache.avro.Schema s1 = s.getSchema();
                for (Field f : s1.getFields()) {
                    counter++;      
                    mapping.put(f.name(), null==s.get(f.name())?null:String.valueOf(s.get(counter)));
                    if(f.name().equalsIgnoreCase("reason_code_id")) {
                        BigDecimal numericValue =
                                new Conversions.DecimalConversion()
                                    .fromBytes((ByteBuffer)s.get(f.name()) , Schema.create(s1.getType()), s1.getLogicalType());
                        System.out.println("Numeric Con"+numericValue);
                    }
                    else {
                            System.out.println("Else Condition "+f.name());
                    }
                }
                ```

    Facing Issue:

    2019-05-24 (14:10:37) org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Can't create a: RECORD

    StackTrace

    java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: gs://trusted-bucket/mgp/temp/BigQueryExtractTemp/3a5365f1e53d4dd393f0eda15a2c6bd4/000000000000.avro range [0, 65461)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:596)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:361)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:194)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:411)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:380)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:306)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Can't create a: RECORD
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.create(Schema.java:120)
        at com.globalpay.WelcomeEmail.mapRecordToObject(WelcomeEmail.java:118)
        at com.globalpay.WelcomeEmail.access$0(WelcomeEmail.java:112)
        at com.globalpay.WelcomeEmail$1.apply(WelcomeEmail.java:54)
        at com.globalpay.WelcomeEmail$1.apply(WelcomeEmail.java:1)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase$1.apply(BigQuerySourceBase.java:221)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase$1.apply(BigQuerySourceBase.java:214)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.AvroSource$AvroBlock.readNextRecord(AvroSource.java:567)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.BlockBasedSource$BlockBasedReader.readNextRecord(BlockBasedSource.java:209)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.advanceImpl(FileBasedSource.java:484)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.startImpl(FileBasedSource.java:479)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.OffsetBasedSource$OffsetBasedReader.start(OffsetBasedSource.java:249)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:593)
        ... 14 more
````

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryAvroUtils.java#L299. I think you need to deserialize the byte buffer. If this ends up being correct, consider sharing the code that you used. Thanks!

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thanks for the Snippet but its not helping for the time being and it would also make the code more complex because to do the work we need avroType and LogicalAvro and to make those we need TableFieldSchema into our serializableFunction class and from GenericRecord object i don't have idea we can achieve that,So is there any other easier way to read the BigQuery Data into Java Class.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I tried the way you asked and added the code in Way 2 above in Question please take a look and if i am missing please let me know. But According to me GenericRecord class must provide the default conversation for Numeric Data Type Like TableRow read Option Provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall approach is correct. It's hard to figure out exactly what's wrong. Please paste the full stack traces if possible. Also, take a look at examples of how to use the `BigQueryIO.read()`, they might help: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html

And instead of `read()` you can use `readTableRows()` instead and get the parsed values out. Or follow the `TableRowParser` implementation for an example of how such parser would work (it is used in `readTableRows()`): https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/79d478a83be221461add1501e218b9a4308f9ec8/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L449

Also you might want to take a look at snippets here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/77cf84c634381495d45a112a9d147ad69394c0d4/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/snippets/Snippets.java#L168

**Update**

Apparently the feature to read rows with Beam schemas was added recently: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/8620

You should be able to do something along these lines now:

```java
p.apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRowsWithSchema())
  .apply(Convert.to(PojoClass.class));
```

Comment: Hi @Anton I have edited the Question and Added the stack trace details but for more details, you can use the below 2 jobids 1. 2019-06-02_07_22_53-1682006672321983235 and 2. 2019-06-02_07_04_50-17375103946794041526. And i don't want to Read in form of TableRow because its Pretty heavy object and While Reading Huge Data Like 900 Columns with 1.4 Million Records Takes 30 Min.